# Native vs IFrame sandbox with HtmlService in Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, iframe, google-apps-script, sandbox, papaparse

I am fairly new to scripting, so keen to understand the difference between Native and iFrame sandbox modes.

I am having difficulty understanding why certain code works on one and not the other (e.g jquery autocomplete working in Native only and Papaparse working in iFrame only).

Besides [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode) documentation, I cannot seem to find much else explaining the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the article you linked there is this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions

it explains in detail the different restrictions per mode.

as to why one library or another breaks in one mode is too broad to answer without the specific code.

Comment: Thank you @Zig Mandel. I totally missed the reference to the HtmlService restrictions link you provided.  A simple change to the jQuery UI library (ensuring it was **https**) solved my issue - autocomplete now works in iFrame.  Much appreciated.